# Functional completeness of ¬ and ∧

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need to show that ¬ and ∧ are a functionally complete set of logical operators, but I'm completely stumped on how to approach proving that I can replace *p → q* and *p ↔ q* with these two logical operators.

I'm a complete beginner at this, so I appreciate any help I can get

Comment: Once you get $\lor$, it’s easy: $p\to q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$, and $p\leftrightarrow q$ is equivalent to $(p\to q)\land(q\to p)$.

Comment: I got stuck at *¬p* ∨ *q* and wasn't sure where to go from there, so I assumed I was doing something wrong. Where do I go from there?

Comment: Have you figured out how to get $p\lor q$?

Comment: No, I don't know how to get rid of the negative on *p*

Comment: That’s not what I asked. Forget about $\neg p\lor q$ for a moment; how do you get $p\lor q$?

Comment: By doing ¬p⇒q right?

Comment: No: you don’t yet have implication. How do you get $p\lor q$ using only the connectives $\neg$ and $\land$? That’s the first step to getting everything.

Comment: I have to shut down for the night, but I’ll leave a hint: start with the De Morgan law that $\neg(p\lor q)$ is equivalent to $\neg p\land\neg q$, and tinker with it a bit.